# rigid collapse to $\aleph_1$

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

Suppose $\kappa$ is inaccessible (or more).  Does there exist a $\kappa$-c.c. partial order $\mathbb P \subseteq V_\kappa$ that forces $\kappa = \aleph_1$, with the following property?-- Whenever $G \subseteq \mathbb P$ is generic over $V$, there does not exist any $H \not= G$ in $V[G]$ which is also $\mathbb P$-generic over $V$.

Comment: I imagine that some Easton iteration which collapses the regular cardinals below $\kappa$ while coding the generic into some definable real might do the trick?

Comment: If $\kappa$ is weakly compact, then every real added by $\mathbb P$ exists in an intermediate model by a forcing of size $<\kappa$.

Comment: Well. Iterate the whole thing with coding the generic into a real or something?

Comment: Sounds promising.  I don't know this technique.

Comment: It's due to Jensen(maybe?), and covered in the section on class forcing in the Handbook.

Comment: It's just almost disjoint coding. Only in this case, try interleaving it with the collapses. So collapse a cardinal, and start coding its generic. Perhaps starting with adding $\kappa$ Cohen reals for good posterity could help to ensure that you have enough reals for that. If you want some other properties, we can discuss about that.

Comment: @NotMike: Not that kind of coding, the much much much simpler one for coding a subset of $\omega_1$ into a real.

Comment: Monroe, actually, thinking about it, Jensen and Solovay's original paper about almost disjoint coding also has them coding the collapse of an inaccessible cardinal to be $\omega_1$.

Comment: @Asaf Oh! The easy one. My bad.

Comment: I will have to look at the Jensen-Solovay paper then. If you add $\kappa$ Cohen reals, then this part of the forcing that has many automorphisms.  Hi Michael.

Comment: Monroe, sure, you have many automorphisms *at first*. But then you can code the entire generic—Cohen reals included—into a single real.

Comment: Please, prove it if you can. It might be more delicate than you think.

Comment: Hi Monroe. https://i.imgur.com/xBwMRmt.gifv

Comment: @Monroe: I'm too lazy to do math properly right now. It's too hot, and my mind is over saturated with regular expressions. I'm coming back to Vienna on Tuesday, we can meet on Wednesday and talk about it, if no reasonable answer will be posted by then (by myself included).

Comment: @Asaf, sounds great! I didn't know you were coming.

Comment: Man, I have a position in the TU waiting for me since March or something. I was already there for a month, had to go back to Israel to get a visa...

Comment: Congrats! Yeah Austria is not the kindest about immigration. Not that my country can say better.

Comment: Well. I'll definitely drop by the KGRC sometime next week.

Comment: @MonroeEskew do you need any special structure of $\kappa$ preserved? I only ask because a countably closed collapse of $\kappa$ to $\omega_2$ followed by Namba sounded interesting. (Namba doesn't add reals under the right assumptions.)

Comment: @NotMike, well, that would collapse $\kappa$, and I am looking for $\kappa$-c.c.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is positive when $\kappa$ is Mahlo.  Please email me for a draft if you are interested.

Comment: I'd be interested to see the write up. However, I don't have a current email for you, complicating things.